# Check to see if the same value was selected if more than one dropdown was added to the page using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, select

What would be the best method of checking the following using jquery:

Check to see if the same value was selected if more than one dropdown was added to the page using jquery

I have a single dropdown on a page:

```
<select name="brand" class="brands" onchange="some function to check for the same value>
 <option>Brand 1</option>
 <option>Brand 2</option>
 <option>Brand 3</option>
</select>
```

I also have the ability to add more dropdowns dynamically. Each dynamic dropdown uses the same data for the options. So i could have this when i click the add button to display a new dropdown:

```
<select name="brand_1" class="brands" onchange="some function to check for the same value">
 <option>Brand 1</option>
 <option>Brand 2</option>
 <option>Brand 3</option>
</select>
```

and again:

```
<select name="brand_2" class="brands" onchange="some function to check for the same value">
 <option>Brand 1</option>
 <option>Brand 2</option>
 <option>Brand 3</option>
</select>
```

etc etc...

I am guessing I could use the class element and perhaps the onchange() event of the dropdown in jquery but not sure of the best way of doing this.
Any ideas or help in pointing me in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

thanks

JC

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be a solution. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/UtNJD/1/)
But it will only work is the `select` elements are one after another.

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val(); // get the value of the current changed select
    var i = $(this).index(); // get it's index (position in the group starting from 0)
    $('select:not(:eq('+i+'))').each(function () { // loop through each select 
        if ($(this).val() === val) { // check if the value of the next select 
                                     // is the same as the changed one
            alert($(this).index()+' has the same value'); 
            // alert the ones with the same value 
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer. I should have mentioned we are using jquery version 1.6.4. I get the following error which i think is connected to the jquery version we are using: $("select").on is not a function

Comment: Ok i have got rid of the error thanks for that, the issue i now have is if i change the first select to 2 and the second to 2 i get the message which is correct. If i then change the first select box back to 1 i still get the same error message even though its been changed back, any ideas? This same behaviour happens in your fiddle example as well.

Comment: no sorry i have worded that wrong, your 2nd solution now removes the js error which is spot on but the behaviour is not quite right as per above.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve which `select` have the same values? or know if there are duplicates or not?

Comment: Just knowing if a dupilcate value has been selected on the form would be sufficient.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/UtNJD/10/ the function below will return true if two or more selected values are the same

Comment: Hey Spooky good work. There is only a slight bug that i'm seeing, in IE, i get two popup messages in FF i get one.

Comment: I don't seem get that problem, which IE ?

Comment: I'm seeing this in Internet Explorer 8